# Finding the additonal angle in a simple geometry question

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am having trouble figuring out a specific angle work out a solution. The question asks me to find the distance of the green vector. Which I know how to do, I would arrive at that value by using a combination of the law of sines and cosines. What I'm having trouble with figuring out is how to get the necessary $15^{\circ}$ to use the above mentioned tools. This is an example from a text I'm working with and they are handwavy with stating that the angle opposite the green vector is $15$. I've tried a multitude of things like using a transversal, droawing a right triangle down from $B$ to an extended vector from $W$. But I can't see how to get the $15^{\circ}$. The only thing coming to mind is that they "assumed" that the triangle made $45^{\circ}$ angles if I make a right triangle, but I'm not "convinced" it is an assumption. Am I missing some geometric idea to get the desired angle?

Note: I cannot embed a picture yet since I am new so the link was automatically inserted instead.

[Finding the value outside of $30^{\circ}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noAqu.png)

Comment: There has to be more information other than your alleging a handwave of $15^\circ$.

Comment: I updated the picture with the question added so you can see all the details.

Comment: If the "southwest" in the question really means southwest, then $\angle ABC$ would really be $15^\circ$.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense as you mention it. Then it is because of the southwest that we can assume the $45^{\circ}$ and hence get the $15^{\circ}$. Thank you for your help